# Direct to Indirect Speech

Tags: reported-speech

May I please check how to convert the following direct speech to indirect?

> Mary asked me "can you do it"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Mary asked me if I could do it* if the conversation was in the past.

If it was a recent conversation and 'it' still hasn't been done, *Mary asked me if I can do it* might be more appropriate.

Note that, in direct speech, the quoted words should begin with a capital letter - "Can you do it?"

Answer (score -1):

A few different ways you can do this.

> I heard mary ask "can you do it?"
>
> Mary said "can you do it?" to him.
>
> She said "can you do it?".

There are definitely other ways, but it just comes down to you playing around with the words. I'd be happy to help further if you provided more text.

Comment: These are not indirect speech because they still quote the speaker's words.

Comment: I heard Mary ask "Can you do it?" uses standard punctuation (the offsetting introductory comma being surely considered optional nowadays), but is still in 'direct speech' format, as Kate says. Using the quotative verb _say_ before a direct question  is non-standard unless one is stressing a person's actual wording ('No, Mary didn't use the verb _perform_, she said "Can you do it?" ')